# Express.js render data from external API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function to get data from an external API:

```
app.get("/getdata", (req, res) => {
  request.get({
    url: 'http://externalurl',
    json: true
  })
  .pipe(res);
});
```

It just shows the received JSON object in a browser. The question is, how could I render this data in a template like it's usually done with express methods like `res.render("template", {data:data})` so that I could format it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `request` variable comes from the [request npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), you can use a callback function to receive the response data:

```
app.get("/getdata", (req, res, next) => {
    request.get("http://externalurl", (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.render("template", {data: JSON.parse(body)});
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you're not comfortable with using calllbacks, you can either wrap the `request` call in a promise or use a ready-made wrapper (please refer to the package's readme for recommendations).

Comment: Gives me `TypeError: res.render is not a function`

Comment: My bad. Typed `res` instead of `response` in the second line. Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem!